# SQL DataSource Exception

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am reposting my Question

I have a Database Object where Database Connection can be established through Database object which is set as a Context Parameter.

```
    ServletContext s=e.getServletContext();    
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/job_portal","root","root");
    s.setAttribute("db_connect",con);
```

I wanted to use the Database Object in my JSP Page using Sql taglib to Connect database and store the data

```
<sql:update dataSource="${applicationScope.db_connect}" >
  insert into linkedin_table values(?,?)
  <sql:param value="${param.Reference_Person}" />
  <sql:param value="${param.Reference_Person_Position}" />
  </sql:update>
```

But its throwing the Exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: 'dataSource' is neither a String nor a javax.sql.DataSource
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you pass Connection, not DataSource.

I don't see a valid reason to connect to DB in JSP. But for the sake of discussion you can do this:

```
DataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
dataSource.setUsername("root");
dataSource.setPassword("root");
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/job_portal");

ServletContext s=e.getServletContext();  
s.setAttribute("db_connect",con);
```

Comment: Tanx for the explain,I understood the difference from your explanation.is there any other way i can use that DB object in JSP and establish connection

Comment: You shouldn't use DB object in your JSP at all. JSP is for rendering stuff. Leave DB logic in server, and pass to JSP only the data it needs to present.